# How to load template in angular after controller finishes loading parameters?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

The problem I have encountered is that the template is loaded earlier than the parameters in the controller and so the user sees empty blocks.

Controller:

```
app.controller('mainDashboardApi', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('api/dashboard/main').success(function(data) {
            $scope.dashboard = data;
        });
    }
]);
```

Router:

```
$stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "dashboard",
        controller: 'mainDashboardApi'
    })
```

How can I make the template load after the parameters finish loading?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a number of things you could do.

You could hide the empty blocks, and only show them when the data has loaded:

```
app.controller('mainDashboardApi', ['$scope', '$http',
    function($scope, $http) {
        $scope.isLoading = true;

        $http.get('api/dashboard/main').success(function(data) {
            $scope.dashboard = data;
            $scope.isLoading = false;
        });
    }
]);
```

That would be the manual way.

But `ui.router` supports this sort of scenario (as does `ngRoute`) with a `resolve` parameter of a state, where you could delay loading a view until all the promises are resolved (or one of the is rejected):

```
$stateProvider
    .state('dashboard', {
        url: "/dashboard",
        templateUrl: "dashboard",
        controller: 'mainDashboardApi',
        resolve: {
          dashboard: function($http){
             return $http.get('api/dashboard/main')
                      .then(function(response){
                         return response.data;
                      })'
          }
        }
    })
```

Then, `dashboard` could be injected (like you would other services) into `mainDashboardApi` controller:

```
app.controller('mainDashboardApi', ['$scope', 'dashboard',
    function($scope, dashboard) {
        $scope.dashboard = dashboard;
    }
]);
```